# Как запретить разворачивание видео на весь экран на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: видео

Как запретить разворачивание видео на весь экран на мобильных устройствах? При включение такого видео на мобильном оно разворачивается на весь экран автоматом.

```html
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10ый Сафари на Айфоне [не станет разворачивать видео](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH11-DontLinkElementID_13) на весь экран, если добавить атрибут `playsinline`:

> When the `playsinline` property is specified, Safari on iPhone allows videos to play inline. Videos without the property will commence playback in fullscreen, but users can pinch close on the video to continue playing the video inline.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls playsinline>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: А для более старых версий и на андроиде?